# Formatting text output in shiny data table using formattable--seems to have stopped working

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, formattable

I had a data table that worked in shiny using the formatting examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html)

The code seems to have stopped working, and instead of a table that is formatted with positive numbers green, negative numbers red, and zero as black, I get a blank output.

For a **reproducible example**, I used mtcars as a simple shiny example with minimal other code "overhead".

The end goal is to format a table so that the numbers in the table show up colored according to the above.

Appreciate the help!

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(tidyverse)


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("example"),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("Table")
        )
    )


# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
    

    # Create formattable function for tables
    sign_formatter <- formatter("span",
                                style = x ~ style(
                                    color = ifelse(x > 0, "green",
                                                   ifelse(x < 0, "red", "black")),
                                    font.weight = "bold"
                                ))


    
    # Identify numeric columns of table
    numeric_cols <- colnames(mtcars[sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)])

    

    # Render the table
    output$Table <- renderDataTable({

    table_to_return <- as.datatable(
        formattable(
            mtcars,
            list(
                area(, numeric_cols) ~ sign_formatter
            )
        )  # formattable close
        )  # datatable close
    })     # Render close
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because the package was not mentioned for `dataTableOutput`.  Change it to `DT::dataTableOutput` and `DT::renderDataTable`

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("example"),
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("Table")
  )
)


# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  # Create formattable function for tables
  sign_formatter <- formatter("span",
                              style = x ~ style(
                                color = ifelse(x > 0, "green",
                                               ifelse(x < 0, "red", "black")),
                                font.weight = "bold"
                              ))
  
  
  
  # Identify numeric columns of table
  numeric_cols <- colnames(mtcars[sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)])
  
  
  
  # Render the table
  output$Table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    table_to_return <- 
     as.datatable(
      formattable(
        mtcars,
        list(
          area(, numeric_cols) ~ sign_formatter
        )
      )  # formattable close
    )  # datatable close
  })     # Render close
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Akrun!  That was indeed it.  I will accept the answer (SO is making me wait a few more minutes).  I have not run into needing to specify that package before...is that because DT and data.table have conflicts/masking?

Comment: @DaveM When I checked for `?dataTableOutput` it returns `shiny` and in `DT`.  It may be better to specify the correct package to avoid masking